# Live Wallpaper in preview mode

Tags: android, live-wallpaper

I need my wallpaper to act differently when in preview mode (the screen with "Settings" and "Set .. "). How do i know when it's drawn there?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Within `onCreateEngine()` you can use the `isPreview()` method.

Note that `onCreateEngine()` is "normally" called twice: once to create an instance for preview, and then again when you actually set the wallpaper.

Details here: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/service/wallpaper/WallpaperService.Engine.html

Comment: Just to be sure, are both engines running simultaniously, or is the seconds `onCreateEngine()` call after the first one was closed? I'm asking because my preference change event is firing twice.

Comment: @ruud-lenders Sorry to be so slow to reply, but I've left programming behind for now, and don't check this site often. My guess is that the first is destroyed before the second is created, so as not to consume double the memory, etc., but that's just a guess. Perhaps, if you're still working in this arena, you could investigate and add another comment to report your findings. This reply has gotten nine upvotes, so apparently this is an issue others face, too. Best of luck to you either way :-) George

Answer (score 5):

The `isPreview()` method can be called in the `onCreate(SurfaceHolder holder)` method of the implemented Engine. Not in the `onCreateEngine` method as the prior answer because the method is not ready.

Answer (score 1):

I'll write in addition to represented answers.
As the preview and non-preview engine instances could exist simultaneously, you can add two static instances and one local variable of your engine inside your WallpaperService class (sample in Kotlin):

```
    private var engine: OpenGLEngine? = null
    private set
    //...

    companion object {
       private var engineInstance: OpenGLEngine? = null
       private var previewEngineInstance: OpenGLEngine? = null
       //...
    }
```

and use them in overriding functions

```
     override fun onCreate(surfaceHolder: SurfaceHolder?) {
        super.onCreate(surfaceHolder)
        if (isPreview) {
            previewEngineInstance = this@OpenGLEngine
            engine = previewEngineInstance
        } else {
            engineInstance = this@OpenGLEngine
            engine = engineInstance
        }
        //...
    }

    override fun onDestroy() {
        if (isPreview) {
            engine = engineInstance
            previewEngineInstance = null
        } else {
            engine = previewEngineInstance
            engineInstance = null
        }
        //...
        super.onDestroy()
    }
```

This way you can always get the current engine instance in your WallpaperService and call its ***isPreview***.